# Can't copy and paste directories from Eclipse(Helios) to Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Cannot copy and paste directories from Eclipse(Helios) to Windows.
The same problem is replicated in FlashBuilder 4.5.
It gives an error "cannot paste clipboard contents into selected items"

Comment: Why don't you go to your workspace directory in windows and copy the directory from there?

Comment: I can drag N drop the directory to the destination.No need to go workspace directory. N i needed a solution not a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

I get this if I'm cutting and pasting a JAR from an *archive* (.rar, .zip, etc).

To fix it in that case, extract the file(s) from the archive first, then cut-and-paste the file into Eclipse.  Works for me under Package Explorer, too.

Answer (score 0):

While using eclipse, some of the files and directories will be in use and cannot be copy pasted to another place. Close the eclipse, if running, and then do it by going to the place where it has been dumped, in your system.

Comment: I have not only tried to close eclipse but also restarted PC several times.I am facing problem from month or so.But can't bear it now wanted a solution.

Comment: What does it say when you try to copy out the dir's ? Does it mention any specific file or jar which is in use ?

Comment: No it does not notify anything.I just simply copy from eclipse and paste on disk the paste option is disable.

Answer (score 0):

if any one has the same problem, goto

```
project->clean
```

works for me